# Get data-value if a element has active class dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic

I have html that has a different **data-value** set

```html
<li :class="category == 1095 ? 'child' : ''" ;="" class="child">
    <a class="child post_no active" data-value="3" @click="filterPosts(1095)">option 1 (3)</a>
</li>
```

I am trying to set a dynamic variable to store the data-value depending on what list item is active.

**This is what I have tried**

```js
jQuery("li.a").each(function () {
  // loop through all li a
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) {
    // check if li a has active class
    console.log($(this).data("value")); // get the value of data-interest attribute
  }
});
```

I also have this:

```js
var itemType = jQuery("ul.filter-list").find("li.active").data("itemtype");
alert(itemType);
```

When I click a new item in the menu it does not refresh the data. I need a way for the data-value to update on the click of a new menu item.

**UPDATE**

How to have this re run when a option is selected

```
let active = jQuery(".active")
let itemType = jQuery('ul.filter-list').find("ul li .active").data('itemtype');
console.log(itemType);
```

**option**

```
<li :class="category == <?php echo $category->term_id; ?> ? 'child' : ''" ;>
                     <a class="child post_no" data-value="<?php echo $total_posts_child ?>" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html( $category->name ); echo " ". "(" .$total_posts_child . ")"; ?></a>
                </li>
```

**Whats needed**

When click a option (list item) to re run the Jquery

**end goal**

to update the **total** with a number that changes dynamically depending on option selected

```
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
    posts: "",
    limit: 6,
    category: 0,
    post_type_js: post_id,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,
    offset: 0,
    total = 0, // change this depending on data-value
    
    filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
        this.total = 0; // change this depending on data-value
        this.fetchPosts();
    },
    
    loadMore() {
        this.loadingMore = true;
        this.total = 0; // change this depending on data-value
        this.offset += 6;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.fetchPosts(true);
    },
```

**Idea**

On click can i post $total_posts_child to my apline Js total ?

```
<a class="child post_no" data-value="<?php echo $total_posts_child ?>" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html( $category->name ); echo " ". "(" .$total_posts_child . ")"; ?></a>
```

**My AJAX**

```
 <?php // the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');

function filterPosts()
{
    $response = [
        'posts' => "",
    ];
    
    $all_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // returns all posts
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    
    $filter_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    
     if ($_POST['limit']) {
        $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = max (0, (int) $_POST['limit']);
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['offset'])) {                      
        $filter_args['offset'] = max (0, (int)$_POST['offset']);
    }

     if ($_POST['post_type_js']) {
        $filter_args['post_type'] = $_POST['post_type_js'];
    }

    if ($_POST['category']) {
        $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
        
        // Get the total number of posts for the category

    //   $filter_args = (int) $_POST['limit'] * (int) $_POST['total'];
       
    //   $_POST["total"] = ($no_of_posts->publish + $no_of_posts->draft + $no_of_posts->disabled);
    }

$total_query_posts = $filter_query->found_posts;
    $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);


    if ($filter_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($filter_query->have_posts()) : $filter_query->the_post();
            $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

Comment: `$("ul li .active").data(...` (note the spaces) will retrieve the data from the *first* active only - if there's only mean to be one, that's fine.

Comment: thanks @freedomn-m will this dynamically change if i click on a new option that changes the active state ?

Comment: jQuery selections (eg `$(".active")`) always run at the time the code runs.  If you *store*/*cache* that, eg `let active = $(".active")` then it won't be "live".

Comment: So jQuery wont how to update this var dynamically ?

Comment: That's not how "var"s work in general.

Comment: Just put the `$(".active")` just before you need it, don't store the result in a *global* variable and you'll be ok.

Comment: Have just updated the question, as im not sure, need the var to be dynamic, so i can use the var in a different function

Comment: You seem to have got stuck on `var` - your original issue was entirely because your selector was missing a space!

Comment: In your `Alpine.data` ... `total = jQuery('ul.filter-list').find("ul li .active").data('value');` - based on the first HTML snippet provided.

Comment: still getting total undefined, in console and the network request

Comment: Do you use a SPA or something?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look at a few aspects of your jQuery function. You use `jQuery` instead of `$` and then use the `$` in the `console.log`. This does not cause any issues, but for readability, it is recommended to stick with one for consistency.

Now to the error. The selector you're using in jQuery ("`li.a`") will try to find list items with the class "`a`", which doesn't match your HTML structure. The proper way to select a child element of a certain tag, for your example, is to do `$('li a')`, however, it would be better to include your class names: `$('li.child a.child.post_no.active')`

So wrapping it all up, this is how I would refactor your method:

```js
$("li.child a.child.post_no").each(function () {
  // loop through all li a with specified classes
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    // check if li has active class
    console.log($(this).data("value")); // get the value of data-interest attribute
  }
});
```

Comment: `$("li.child a.child.post_no.active")  ..  .hasClass("active")`?

Comment: thanks @Zach however its not working for me

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Beep I checked your post updates, I don't think I can help you anymore. I don't have much experience with Alipine or Ajax.

Comment: @ZachTheDev lulz - I would have gone the other way `li a.active` then you know they're all .active already and don't need the .hasClass at all.

Comment: @freedomn-m I would agree, but I wanted to keep the snippet as close to the original posters to point out the mistake. I would do it the way you mentioned.